# Nullpointer database.open(), getwritabledatabase

Tags: sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-context

I want to fill a list and do this from a database opened in the activity. I made a custom adapter and that 'helper' class calls another 'helper' class the listview wrapper. In that listview wrapper I want to open another (different) database, but I get a nullpointer exception.

So in the activity I call:

```
 adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, ListViewAdapter.TPL_HISTORY, historydatasource.getAllCalls());
             list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Than the historydatasource class opens a listviewwrapper (helper) class that handles the templates I created for the listview. There I want to open another database, but I get a nullpointer exception.

Anybody an idea how I can do this?

```
        DB_DataSource cardsdatasource=new DB_DataSource(myContext);
cardsdatasource.open(); (GIVES NULLPOINTER, because myContext=null)
```

Is there a way to get the context?

The error:

```
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at com.myapp.testapp.ListViewWrapper.populateFrom(ListViewWrapper.java:91)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at com.myapp.testapp.ListViewAdapter.getView(ListViewAdapter.java:121)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1536)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:718)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:775)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1646)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1366)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1146)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1866)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-20 14:03:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(15492):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Share the code of method `open`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was indeed a context issue, I passed activity.getApplicationContext() from the CustomAdapter to the wrapper and is was solve.

Answer (score 0):

The way in which i make my `DataSource` class is as follows:

```
public class StudyManagerDataSource {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "studymanager";

    SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase database;        

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public StudyManagerDataSource(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DBOpenHelper(context);

    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void open() {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Database Opened");
    } // end method open

    public void close() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Database Closed");
        dbHelper.close();
    } // end method close
    /*
    Other methods for manipulating tables goes here...
       */    
}
```

Tell me if it has solved your problem!